# GWT. How to disable TabBar?

Tags: java, gwt

I want to disable TabBar in GWT's TabPanel and prevent user from direct choosing Tab(Tab's will be changed automatically).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TabPanel.getTabBar().setTabEnabled()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabBar.html#setTabEnabled%28int,%20boolean%29)